# angularjs How to escape “${variable}” in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-escape-characters

I want to show a string like ${date} to the div element:

```
<div>please use the ${date} as the substitute tag to the name</div>
```

the content will be display like:

```
please use the ${date} as the substitute tag to the name.
```

but the browser regards the ${date} as a javascript variable, so how to escape the ${date} string within angularjs?

Comment: you can check for [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) services. or you can use `<code>` or `<pre>` tag instead of `<div>`

Comment: As long as you don't change the start and end interpolation tags, you shouldn't have any problems with that string, that not being considered an expression.

Comment: I try the <code> or <pre> tag but it doesn't work.$sce services maybe could solve my problem, but it seems redundant.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu, I use another start and end interpolation tags because I use it with django.

Answer (score 1):

Make a method in your controller to hand the string back to the template:

```
specialText() {
  return '${date}';
}
```

Then in your template:

```
<div>please use the {{vm.specialText()}} as the substitute tag to the name</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in JS add `$sce` as DI

`$scope.stringVar = $sce.trustAsHtml('please use the ${date} as the substitute tag to the name');`

in HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="stringVar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `&#36;` instead of writing $ in your code. It is the HTML representation for the dollar sign, and should prevent that expression from being recognized as a variable.

```
<div>please use the &#36;{date} as the substitute tag to the name</div>
```

You can find a full list of these codes [at the W3 Character Entity Reference.](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, I have resolve the problem in an elegant way.

I replace the string `${date}` with `{{"\${date}"}}` and it works. It means that the browser regards the `"\${date}"` as a angularjs expression which is referenced to the constant string value.

By the way, `$` is a special character in string, we should add an escape character `\` before it.

Answer (score 0):

A light-weight workaround without escape characters:
Split your expression and wrap inner part in span, as below.

```
<div>please use the ${<span>date</span>} as the substitute tag to the name</div>
```